# Can I open a folder of a live web site with WebMatrix2?

Tags: asp.net, html, webmatrix

I want to edit a web site using WebMatrix, however the site was created with ASP.net, When I open the folder of My site I Get so many errors, I just want to know if I can edit the web site ?

Thank you for your Help :)

Comment: I don't get it, is it stopping you from editing the files?

Comment: @VoidKing it's stopping me to edit my ASP pages it does not recognize the HTML tags: <frame>, <frameset>, <noframe>, width, valign ...

Comment: Yeah, I get that on certain things, too, but I have since coded things a bit different to avoid as many errors as possible, but it doesn't "break" your site. WebMatrix's Intellisense is just trying to keep you using today's (or rather the DOCTYPE you specify's) best practices. If the site works for you otherwise, it will be fine to ignore them. Certain things can be converted however, for your benefit, such as the fact that the valign attribute is not necessary as their is a CSS rule for that (e.g., `vertical-align: middle;`). Also, I was told to stay away from frames (maybe use iframe?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can edit the site. Even with the errors (even if something wasn't accessible in WebMatrix, couldn't you just open it up in say, notepad, or some other text editor?)

WebMatrix uses ASP.NET (many times in the form of C#.net, but certainly not always, as it has other options, not the least of which being VB.net).

Is it stopping you from something?

**----------------------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------------------**

I get those errors on certain things, too, but I have since coded things a bit different to avoid these errors (can't seem to find a suitable replacement for "unselectable" that works in IE, so I accept that error [many people will claim that their is CSS for that, which their is, but NOT for IE, no matter what they say]), but it doesn't "break" your site. WebMatrix's Intellisense is just trying to keep you using today's (or rather the DOCTYPE you specify's) best practices. If the site works for you otherwise, it will be fine to ignore them. Certain things can be converted however, for your benefit, such as the fact that the valign attribute is not necessary as their is a CSS rule for that (e.g., `vertical-align: middle;`). Also, I was told to stay away from frames (maybe use iframe?), but again, if it works for you, it works for you. WebMatrix is just an IDE, after all. IIS works as IIS always has (except maybe for the fact that WebMatrix uses IIS Express, but that has never hindered me from doing anything, so far...).

Honestly, though, for a lot of the errors you are having, you should be using CSS for instead of HTML. This would clear most of that stuff up for you, and you would be compliant with best practices, which is always advantageous (for SEO if nothing else).

I will state that I know WebMatrix supports both PHP and classic ASP.

Here's a link on that very detail (the classic ASP detail):

http://www.quickersite.com/r/default.asp?iID=HFJJLH&iPostID=MFDIFG

**----------------------------------------SHORT ANSWER---------------------------------------------**

Yes you can edit your website in WebMatrix.  If it is valid markup to the browser that renders it, it will render. WebMatrix's errors will have no affect on it. Obviously this isn't true for your server-side code, though (C#, ASP, PHP, VB, or whatever you're using).

Comment: Yeah! I get so many errors with the HTML tags, like: 
This document type is not supported. IntelliSense and validation for this document type will be based on HTML 5.

    Unknown element 'frame' or element cannot be placed here.

    Element 'frame' cannot be nested inside element 'html'.

    Element 'font' cannot be nested inside element 'td'.

    Unknown attribute 'height'.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your explanation, this was so Helpfull !

Comment: @Hanane You're very welcome. Let me know if you're having trouble figuring out how to fix any of the errors and I'll be glad to help you further. Sometimes it's hard to tell what all is deprecated these days.

Comment: I have some troubles when I execute my ASP pages I get this error in the browser:  

     Active Server Pages (ASP) erreur 'ASP 0131'  

     Parent path unauthorized /Admin/nimda_cansu.asp, ligne 1  

     The include file '.. / Inc / Inc.asp' can not contain '..' to indicate the parent directory.  
=============  
This is what I have in the first line of my asp code:  
`<!--#include file="../Inc/Inc.asp"-->`  
------------------  
I've activated the parent path, but I still have this error !

Comment: @Hanane Well, I have only barely dabbled in ASP before, but the error message sounds like it is telling you one of two things: **1)** You need elevation (i.e., you need to provide administrator privelages) OR **2)** The syntax it is expecting to navigate up one directory is not `..` in the given environment.  Anyway, that is a best guess for me, as you probably know more about ASP than I do. May I suggest posting another question on SO, with the ASP tag? Remember to provide plenty of error detail, explanations on what you've tried, and any research you may have done on the issue.

Comment: @Hanane I see you have already posted that question. This is probably a dumb question, but did you try Googling the error code/scenario you are encountering? Maybe that can help?

Comment: I've tried Googling the error code, but I didn't find too much about it..
Im searching again.. Thank you so much for your remarks!